# Unwanted bold-face while putting multiple ggplot charts in the same file

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, mclapply

I don't know if you have seen some unwanted bold-face font like picture below:

[image]

As you see the third line is bold-faced, while the others are not. This happens to me when I try to use `ggplot()` with `lapply()` or specially `mclapply()`, to make the same chart template based on different data, and put all the results as different charts in a single PDF file.

One solution is to avoid using `lapply(x, f)` when `f()` is a function that returns a `ggplot()` plot, but I have to do so for combining charts (i.e. as input for `grid.arrange()`) in some situation.

Sorry not able to provide you reproducible example, I tried really hard but was not successful because the size of code and data is too big with several nested functions and when I reduced complexity to make a reproducible example, the problem did not happen.

I asked the question because I guessed maybe someone has faced the same experience and know how to solve it.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: He's right. I suspect I know what is causing this, but try again with the reproducible example. If nothing else, creating a simple example often helps you find the problem yourself...

Comment: I tried hard again, with small low-complexity programs (as reproducible example) the error does not happen. So I hope somebody has already faced the problem and know how to solve it, even without reproducible example

Comment: Without data and a reproducible example, I can't be sure of the problem, but I have seen stuff like this.  It often has to do with the resolution of the plotting device.  I would first try saving the plot as a PDF to see if the issue is related to anti-aliasing, and then I would try significantly increasing the resolution of the plotting device.  Often, either of these approaches will produce a more accurate visual for me, and a lot of the artifacts I am seeing on the screen just disappear.  This may not be your problem, but perhaps it is a place to start.

Comment: @Dinre Thanks but the output is PDF file, that resolution is not a matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My intuition is that it's not actually being printed in bold, but rather double-printed for some reason, which then looks bold. This would explain why it doesn't come up with a simpler example. Especially given your mention of nested functions and probably other complicated structures where it's easy to get an off-by-one or similar error, I would try doing something where you can see exactly what's being plotted -- perhaps by examining the `length()` of the return value from `apply()`.

Changing the order of elements of the vector, so that the order of the elements in the key is different, may also help. If you consistently get the bold-face on the last element, that also tells you a little bit more about where something is going wrong.

As @Dinre also mentioned, it could also be related to your plotting device. You can try out  changing your plotting device. I have my doubts about this though, seeing as it's not a consistent problem. You could also try changing the position of the key, which depending on your plotting device and settings, may move you in or out of a compression block, thus changing which artifacts crop up.

Answer (score 1):

Reproducible example and a solution **may be** as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
ggplot(data = d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(aes(3,7,label = 'some text 10 times')) +
    geom_text(data = data.frame(x=1,y=1), 
              aes(7,3, label = 'some text one time'))
```

When we try to add a label by `geom_text()` manually inserting `x` and `y` do not shorten the data. Then same label happen to be printed as many times as the number of rows our data has. Data length may be forced to 1 by replacing data within `geom_text()`.

[image: plot]